# Snowflake:SQL compilation error: Virtual column 'TOPIC' is invalid target

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to modify add a column to the table as below

```
Alter table Table_name_A
add column TOPIC VARCHAR(16777216) as 'default_value' ;
```

and the trying to insert values

```
insert into Table_name_A
(TOPIC)
values ('some other topic')
```

this is throwing error : SQL compilation error: Virtual column 'TOPIC' is invalid target.
How to resolve this?

Comment: Replace "as" with key word DEFAULT and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your alter table syntax wrong. Add a column like this instead:

```sql
Alter table Table_name_A add column TOPIC VARCHAR(16777216) default 'default_value';
```

Then you should be able to insert into it. I think the way that you've done it is for external tables.